# How to describe my character using a power

Tags: creative-writing, fantasy

My character has the ability to charm others. She can use her powers of charm to persuade others to do what she wants or daze them for a small period of time. Too much use of this power can drain her energy and make her vulnerable.

I’m having a hard time describing how she uses or activates her powers. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @meadow, welcome to Writing.SE! We cannot write your character for you, but we can help you with figuring out how to write her yourself. To help us help you, please describe what you have tried so far. There are many books, comic books, movies and tv shows with characters that have supernatural powers. I'm sure you are familiar with some of them. What ideas do those other works give you and how does that not fit your character or story? Please add some details so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You might give your character's power a visible cue; an example is the old television situation comedy "Bewitched", wherein the main character twitched her nose when she used her powers. As to your character's activation of her power, you could show her focusing on a certain thought or formula to make her charm-power work, or concentrating on the person she is trying to persuade, and as her energy drains she might experience difficulty in concentration. Physical fatigue could be another sign of over-exertion. The power might also operate as an aura, and therefore have a distance limitation.

Answer (score 1):

**Well, what role does her power(s) play in the story?**

@Stanley Webb gives some suggestions in their answer as to how it may result in fatigue over time, and it may involve a visual cue/clue.

There are multiple reasons as to why those suggestions are useful.

**Working with powers**

Many answers on this site have focused on *how magical/supernatural powers usually function in stories in order for them to be satisfying for the reader.*

One of the things that have been highlighed multiple times is to ensure a kind of balance in the way the power(s) work(s). The idea is, that if a power simply works perfectly, unlimitedly, all the time, it doesn't contribute a very satisfying dynamic to the story. This, in particular, goes for protagonists, as much of **the story** revolves around challenges or conflicts, and resolving said challenges with magic can seem unfulfilling to the reader.

Thus, in order for your power(s) to hold a satisfying role in the story, you may want to take this into account. You should be able to answer the following questions:

- What are her challenges directly associated with her use of powers?
- What are her challenges outside of her using her powers?

If her powers aren't completely disconnected from the challenges in the story, they should play into it.

**How does she use or activate her powers?**

Multiple factors are now presented as (presumably) relevant for the power in the context of your story. Both (potential) visual clues and (potential) fatigue (or similar) should fit the story, and knowing how the power plays into the story should help you in the following ways:

Perhaps a fitting 'solution' is one where the target of her charm may initially 'notice' her acting in a certain way - perhaps only briefly - before being 'under her spell'. They may recollect this initial 'noticing' upon returning to a non-charmed state (making her a suspect?).
Other characters, however, may be(come) very aware of something taking place, perhaps to the point of her attracting a lot of attention from anyone else present.

Once you know how her powers function externally, it makes sense for them to somewhat reflect that internally. It could be demanding or exhausting, or she could need lots of sleep(or water, food, mama, what-have-you) in order to be able, at all, to do it. Perhaps the mere presence of people other than the target(s) makes it near-impossible for her to succeed in charming others, or will make it incredibly exhausting, as, perhaps, "attention" drains her (unbeknownst to her at first). Perhaps she develops a form of paranoia, constantly fearing that people are 'on to her', making her 'addicted to charming others', a sort of 'magical spiralling'-phenomenon.

**Intuitive or taking effort - both mastered**

It could be intuitive, like the feeling of having to sneeze, or it could take a certain effort, like learning how to whistle.
In the case of sneezing, the 'pre-sneeze-sensation' could present itself to her in moments where *her body is ready*. In the case of spiralling, the sensation could present itself to an overwhelming degree.
In the case of whistling, as well as with the sneezing, we could follow her 'path to understanding and mastering' the power.
At some point she could be sneezing or whistling all the time. Both could draw attention to her.

There is no single answer to your questions, but part of the answer lies in answering the question of what role it plays in the story, and making it work in a suitable way. From there, you may simply have to answer the question:
**"If it is supposed to work like this, what should it look or feel like to her?"**